# Change values in Pandas Dataframe [Python]

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to remove the percent sign after a value in a pandas dataframe, relevant code:

```
for i in loansdata:
    if i.endswith('%'):
        i = i[:-1]
```

I was thinking that i = i[:-1] would set the new value, but it doesn't. How do I go about it? For clarity: if I print i inside the for loop, it prints without the percent sign. But if I print the whole dataframe, it has not changed.

Comment: What is `loansdata`, can you post raw data and code to reproduce your df and the desired df, thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `str.replace` to replace a specific character for a column:

```
df[col] = df[col].str.replace('%','')
```

What you're doing depending on what `loansdata` actually is, is either looping over the columns or the row values of a column.

You can't modify the row contents like that, even if you could you should avoid loops where a vectorised solution exists.

If % exists in multiple cols then you could call the above for each col but this method only exists for `str` dtypes